# Center table (table width > screen resolution)

Tags: html, html-table, width, center, resolution

My table/web page is 1250px wide, centered. But for a 1024px wide monitor like mine, i have to scroll "right" to see the whole page. I'd like it centered for a resolution my size so I don't have to scroll.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>blah</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />
</head>
<body>
<table id="Table_01" width="1250" height="1500" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="8">
            <img src="images/site_layout_01.gif" width="148" height="1500" alt=""></td>
        <td colspan="9">
            <img src="images/header-image.jpg" width="968" height="336" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="8">
            <img src="images/site_layout_03.gif" width="134" height="1500" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">
            <img src="images/site_layout_04.gif" width="968" height="71" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/site_layout_05.gif" width="42" height="201" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/review1.jpg" width="195" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/site_layout_07.gif" width="40" height="201" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/review2.jpg" width="195" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/site_layout_09.gif" width="40" height="201" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/review3.jpg" width="195" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/site_layout_11.gif" width="40" height="201" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/review4.jpg" width="195" height="84" alt=""></td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <img src="images/site_layout_13.gif" width="26" height="201" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="images/site_layout_14.gif" width="195" height="117" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/site_layout_15.gif" width="195" height="117" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/site_layout_16.gif" width="195" height="117" alt=""></td>
        <td>
            <img src="images/site_layout_17.gif" width="195" height="117" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">
            <img src="images/main-image.jpg" width="968" height="161" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">
            <img src="images/site_layout_19.gif" width="968" height="9" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">
            <img src="images/obama_quote.gif" width="968" height="63" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="9">
            <img src="images/site_layout_21.gif" width="968" height="659" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? There is no way to center a 1250px wide table so that it is fully visible on a 1024px wide screen so that you don't have to scroll.

Comment: for a 1024px wide monitor i want it center and 226px of the sides(113px each side) can go to hell all i care. thats what i mean

Comment: Can you use javascript for this? It becomes trivial if you can...

Answer (score 0):

use the following css

```
#Table_01{
      margin:0 auto;
      width:1250px;
}
```

Its okay if you want to keep this code for learning purpose, but the common standards say that maintain at [960 px.](http://960.gs/)

Comment: is the table centered anyways? u have to scroll because the table width exceeds the window width.

Comment: im aware of that, but the table doesnt even respond to lowering it's width

Comment: sure it doesn't respond)) You've got its width in the attribute, not css. `<table id="Table_01" width="1250" height="1500"` etc. CORRECTION: it doesn't really matter, sorry, css still changes the width.

Answer (score 0):

you can set table min width to be 1025px and 100%. Even so you will need scroll since there is no way to position bigger glass inside smaller one.

```
#Table_01 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1680px;
  min-width: 1025px;
}
```

**Update:**
From your updated question I guess you want to set equal margins on each side to be 113px. 
You can do that using following.

```
#Table_01 {
    margin: 0 113px 0 113px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first off, ditch the deprecated attributes you have on your table. apply them correctly via css. then add a media query that changes for your screen size

```
#Table_01{margin:0 auto; width:1250px}
@media only screen and (max-width:1024px) { #Table_01{width:1024} }
```

or you could set width:100%

Comment: max-width:12004 is what was there, entirely my fault..but come on dude. look @ what you are doing.

Comment: dude...if you posted working code or on jsfiddle it'd be alot easier. if you noticed THAT you should've pointed it out/edited it.

Comment: its not going to work because of the img sizes...ditch the attributes and serve up separate image sizes in the media query. if you don't like how they're scaling, then simply make them a background-image in a div, and swap out different sized images in the media query.

Answer (score 0):

A terrible (but working) solution would be as follows: You set the width on the table and center it(`width: 1250px; margin: 0 auto;`) - this will center the table on high-res monitors. And then you can set `overflow-x: hidden` on your `body` element (since there are no wrappers) - this will prevent the horizontal scrollbar from appearing.

Comment: and it's impossible to center something big inside of something small... on your monitor the table will still start from the left, and 226 pixels will be cut off from the right side

Comment: Actually you can combine both answers, mine and albert's. If you desperately want to shift your table off the screen to the left on low-res monitors - simply add the `position: relative; left: -113px;` inside a media query, and delete the value for high-res ones, but goodness this is bad

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue of table must be in centre of screen, I found the below solution.

you can add that same line to your table directly:

```
<table style="margin: auto;">
```